# Find devicePixelRatio according to both page zoom level and Windows 10 DPI settings

Tags: javascript, windows, windows-10

I need to expand the `canvas` to full screen, when I'm going to the fullscreen mode in my game.
I use `screen.width` and `screen.height` to detect the screen size.
The problem is, if screen scale settings in Windows 10 are set not to 100%, `screen.width` is less than actual screen size. For ex., if it is 150% scale in Windows settings, screen.width is 1280, but in the page space it is still 1920 px.

I can use `window.devicePixelRatio`, which returns 1.5 in this case, for correcting the size. But the page zooming also affects `devicePixelRatio` value.

So, if the page is zoomed to 67% and Windows screen scaling is 150%, `devicePixelRatio` will return 1.0, but `screen.width` returns 1280. But I need the way to know that the screen size is 1920.

The Windows 10 scale settings I'm talking about:
[image: The Windows 10 scale settings I'm talking about]

Comment: The behaviour in Firefox is different, zoom does not affect devicePixelRatio. But yeah, in Chrome this is a problem I don't know how to solve either.

Answer (score 1):

After talking with a Chromium developer related with the dpi feature, it seems that the best you can do is:

```
canvas.width = Math.round(window.screen.width * window.devicePixelRatio / (window.outerWidth / window.innerWidth) / 80) * 80
canvas.height = Math.round(window.screen.height * window.devicePixelRatio / (window.outerWidth / window.innerWidth) / 60) * 60
```

That works in Chrome and Firefox. You might wonder what are the 60 and the 80 numbers doing there. It turns out, that 60 is a common multiple of all the usual resolutions in height, and 80 has the same role for width. So we can use those values to correct weird decimals occuring during those operations.

Then, if the canvas is in fullscreen you can also do:

```
canvas.style.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.style.height = window.innerHeight;
```

Which would work "almost" perfectly. In my case, I notice that for some zoom values, the canvas.style values could be one pixel too short or too long. Because of this, I recommend you to have body.style.overflow = 'hidden' when you use the fullscreen mode and an appropriate background color.

Answer (score 1):

I found this post which led me to the correct solution: https://css-tricks.com/can-javascript-detect-the-browsers-zoom-level/#comment-1802587

```js
declare global {
  interface Window {
    getScreenDetails: () => Promise<{
      currentScreen: {
        devicePixelRatio: number;
      };
    }>;
  }
}

const supportsScreenDetails = "getScreenDetails" in window;

async function getZoomLevel() {
  if (!supportsScreenDetails) {
    return window.devicePixelRatio;
  }

  const screenDetails = await window.getScreenDetails();
  return window.devicePixelRatio / screenDetails.currentScreen.devicePixelRatio;
}

const zoomLevel = await getZoomLevel();
const width = containerDiv.clientWidth * zoomLevel;
const height = containerDiv.clientHeight * zoomLevel;
```